# Nested Linq crashes intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, intellisense

Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (SP1) and developing some code that uses nested LINQ statements. How ever with every level of nesting the intellisense performance drops considerably to the point where it become unusable.

Has anyone else experienced something similar or found a solution to this problem?

Cheers for any help
Tony

---

**Update**
We use resharper, I've change the intellisense back to visual studio and the same thing happens.

I don't have the exact code with me but its something along the lines of:

```
var a = list1.Sum(x => x.list2.Sum(y => y.list3.Sum()))
```

Any deeper nesting and it usually throws a wobbly.

I haven't turned off reshaprer completely but I will try that in the morning.

Thanks for the help so far

---

**Update 2**
I've tested the code on a copy of VS without resharper, and it works fine.....

Comment: Can you post some code that caused the issue?

Comment: I've never seen this and I'm pretty Linq heavy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using CodeRush from Devepress? Try turning it off or [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B90896.aspx) solution (despite being for a different problem) seemed to solve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen it. It's probably related to Visual Studio plug-ins like Resharper or CodeRush; we've seen those plug-ins degrade IDE performance.